# How to use values from one table as column names in a new Table in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| EmployeeName | City |
| --- | --- |
| Maria | Chicago |
| John | Chicago |
| Anna | LA |
| Peter | LA |
| Carrie | NYC |

And I need to create a table that will look like this:

| Chicago | LA | NYC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | Anna | Carrie |
| John | Peter |  |

I found this

```sql
SELECT (ColumnNames)  
FROM (TableName)  
PIVOT
(  
 AggregateFunction(ColumnToBeAggregated)
  FOR PivotColumn IN (PivotColumnValues)
) AS (Alias);
```

But I am confused which aggregate function to use since the values are not numeric and also my table has too many Cities to write them manually.

Comment: That's not a pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can PIVOT with the addition of a new column.  In this simple case I used the window function `dense_rank() over()`

**Results**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([EmployeeName] varchar(50),[City] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Maria','Chicago')
,('John','Chicago')
,('Anna','LA')
,('Peter','LA')
,('Carrie','NYC')
 

Select  *
 From  (
        Select EmployeeName
              ,City
              ,RN = dense_rank() over (partition by city order by EmployeeName desc) 
         From @YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(EmployeeName) for City in ( [Chicago],[LA],[NYC]) )pvt
```

**Results**

```
RN  Chicago LA      NYC
1   Maria   Peter   Carrie
2   John    Anna    NULL
```

**UPDATE- Dynamic Approach**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select  *
 From  (
        Select EmployeeName
              ,City
              ,RN = dense_rank() over (partition by city order by EmployeeName desc) 
         From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(EmployeeName) for City in ( '+ (Select string_agg(quotename(City),',') From  (Select distinct City from YourTable) A) +' ) )pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, the only question I have is if there is a way not to write the City Names (new Column Names) manually, since my first table has 30+ cities.

Comment: @ana996 That would require Dynamic SQL.   What version are you running?   SELECT @@version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 22621: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @ana996  One moment